# hsqlDB procedure select

Tags: java, select, hsqldb, procedure

I have created this procedure who return a single row.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE recuperarUsuario
(USW VARCHAR(15), PAS VARCHAR(25))
READS SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE res CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM ACCESOUSER WHERE USERWIN=USW AND PASS=PAS;
OPEN res;
END;
```

I execute call this procedure in java and this do run. I have used a cursor but isn't necesary.

I have created the similar procedure using four variables but I call this procedure in java and this dont't run.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE recuperar
(IN USW VARCHAR(15), IN PAS VARCHAR(15), OUT USWO VARCHAR(15), OUT PASO VARCHAR(15), OUT TIP VARCHAR(7))
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT userwin, pass, tipo INTO USWO, PASO, TIP FROM ACCESOUSER WHERE USERWIN=USW AND PASS=PAS;
END;
```

What is the my error? Please helpme, thank you for your time.

Comment: do u get any error?
 how do u know it is not running?
maybe u don't call it?
please complete ur question with java code

Comment: You need to report the Java code.

Comment: that the object doesn't exist.
but in the database if compiled.